# Styling individual menu links in Joomla!

Tags: css, joomla, menu

Using Joomla, I have a flat list menu (see image) and am using separator links with images to separate the menu links.

[image]

I'd like to style the menu links (not the separator links) so that they are lifted up slightly and are sitting more centrally among the separator images.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Have you used fire bug or similar to identify the class you need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the menu links a small value of `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is with the Joomla system. I'm not sure how to implement that CSS to individual menu links in Joomla. It seems quite tricky.

Comment: provide a teplate.css file and html-code of page with this menu